# Using range values as a key in a map

Tags: java, maps, range

Let's say that I want my application to determine user's fitness level based on some criteria.

The criteria could be something like: age, currently taking medication?, 400m run

At first I though I could create a Map where the value is the fitness level and the key is an object that has all the criteria, but since the criteria are ranges this wouldn't work.

For example:
if age is between 18 and 22 and onMedication = false and run400m = [70, 80]

fitness level = GOOD

Now if only one of the parameters is in a different range the fitness level would be different. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a TreeMap class for this. There are very useful methods to deal with ranges of  key values. For example:

```
    TreeMap<Integer, String> myTreeMap = new TreeMap<>();

    myTreeMap.put(10, "A");
    myTreeMap.put(20, "B");
    myTreeMap.put(30, "C");
    myTreeMap.put(40, "D");

    System.out.println(myTreeMap.floorEntry(25));
```

Will be print the second option (20=B). I recommend that you check the TreeMap and all its methods for this case.

Comment: This works fine with this scenario but what If I have multiple ranged parameters each of which is only a partial key to the value in the map?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use OOP and do something like this:

```
public class FitnessApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("age", 17);
        params.put("onMedication", false);
        System.out.printf(new FitnessLevelCalculator().calculateFor(params).name());
    }
}

class FitnessLevelCalculator {
    private LinkedList<FitnessLevel> fitnessLevels = new LinkedList<>();

    public FitnessLevelCalculator() {
        fitnessLevels.add(new FitnessLevel(FitnessLevelEnum.ATHLETIC, Arrays.asList(new RangeCriteria("age", 18, 25), new BooleanCriteria("onMedication", false))));
        fitnessLevels.add(new FitnessLevel(FitnessLevelEnum.GOOD, Arrays.asList(new RangeCriteria("age", 14, 17), new BooleanCriteria("onMedication", false))));
        fitnessLevels.add(new FitnessLevel(FitnessLevelEnum.ILL, Arrays.asList(new RangeCriteria("age", 16, 17))));
    }

    public FitnessLevelEnum calculateFor(Map<String, Object> params) {
        ListIterator<FitnessLevel> listIterator = fitnessLevels.listIterator();
        while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
            FitnessLevel fitnessLevel = listIterator.next();
            if (fitnessLevel.accept(params)) {
                return fitnessLevel.getLevel();
            }
        }

        return FitnessLevelEnum.NOT_CLASSIFIED;
    }
}

enum FitnessLevelEnum {
    ILL, GOOD, ATHLETIC, NOT_CLASSIFIED
}

class FitnessLevel {
    private List<Criteria> criteriaList = new ArrayList<>();
    private FitnessLevelEnum level;

    public FitnessLevel(FitnessLevelEnum level, List<Criteria> criteriaList) {
        this.criteriaList = criteriaList;
        this.level = level;
    }

    public boolean accept(Map<String, Object> params) {
        for (Criteria criteria : criteriaList) {
            if (!params.containsKey(criteria.getName())) {
                return false;
            }
            if (!criteria.satisfies(params.get(criteria.getName()))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public FitnessLevelEnum getLevel() {
        return level;
    }
}

abstract class Criteria<T> {
    private String name;

    public Criteria(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public abstract boolean satisfies(T param);

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

class RangeCriteria extends Criteria<Integer> {
    private int min;
    private int max;

    public RangeCriteria(String name, int min, int max) {
        super(name);
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean satisfies(Integer param) {
        return param >= min && param <= max;
    }
}

class BooleanCriteria extends Criteria<Boolean> {
    private Boolean expectedValue;

    public BooleanCriteria(String name, Boolean expectedValue) {
        super(name);
        this.expectedValue = expectedValue;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean satisfies(Boolean param) {
        return param == expectedValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is nice but a bit of an overkill for what I need it for. I think I can just build a string key based on user parameters and use it to map to the corresponding FitnessLevel in the <String, FitnessLevel> map.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, I don't think it's good to use as a key in Map. There maybe a way to put the Object with all conditions as your business but it's quite complex and not worth to do that. The `Interpreter Pattern` may help you on this.

Hope this help.